# How to convert JSON retrived from exist URL to view in REST Framework using Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to receive JSON from specific URL display in View, Using Django Rest Framework. Combined view from CarViewSet and external json. You can see in my code that i want JSON from   `director_detail = requests.get('http://192.168.10.1/BASIC/GetEmployees/'+direct_id)` combined with **CarViewSet**

Here is my code
**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .models import getData
from .serializers import CarSerializer
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = getData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    __basic_fields = ('plate_no',)
    search_fields = __basic_fields

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = getData.objects.all()
        serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        plateno = self.request.query_params.get('plate_no', None)
        if plateno is not None:
            queryset =  queryset.filter(plate_no=plateno)
            serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            empid= data[0]['empidlong']

            requests.get('http://192.168.10.1/BASIC/GetEmployees/'+empid)
            direct_id =data[0]['director_emp_id']
            director_detail = requests.get('http://192.168.10.1/BASIC/GetEmployees/'+direct_id)
            #director_detail.json()

        return Response(data,director_detail.json())
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: are you trying to combine `data` and `director_detail.json()` into a single object?

Answer (score 0):

If your default renderer is 'JSONRenderer' (documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers)) 
  one possible solution could be to combine *data* and *director_detail.json()* into a single json. Being this what is passed as parameter to Response().

Besides that, probably it would be better to abstract the functionality of the get in 'GetEmployees' endpoint into a function, and use that function in both sites ('GetEmployees' and 'CarViewSet'), instead of making a request inside another request (even more if both belongs to the same app or project, I don't know if this is your case).